# Anonymous subclass

Tags: c#, anonymous-class

How to create an instance of an anonymous subclass in `C#`? Let I have a base class `Bclass` and I want to create an instance of sublclass with an additional method and a property? How is it possible to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anonymous classes (aka [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)) can not extend another class or implement an interface.

If you need inheritance or to implement an interface you need to create a named class.

Comment: But in Java we can create an instance of an anonymous sublclass, isn't it?

Comment: How would you do that? You don't have a class name you could use to create a instance. As soon as you have a name it is a named class, isn't it? P.S.: I am NO Java developer, so it may works (differently) there...

Comment: @chrfin ....what? Anonymous classes in C#? What are you talking about? Do you mean [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)?

Comment: It can be done like the following: Let MyClass is a some class. So anonymous subclass is creating by MyClass m= new MyClass(){ public String str;}

Comment: @dcastro It works fine in Java. My question in the comment was about the Java anonymous subclass.

Comment: @dcastro: Yes, they are normaly called types (I added it to the answer, including your link), but they are also classes. See under "Remarks" in your link: `Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object,...`.